# How to redirect one action to another action in MVC5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to `RedirectToAction` to another action inside of a method. I used:

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

But I am getting an error, it doesn't hit the other action.

**My Controller Code:**

```
public ActionResult VisitCount(VisitorsViewModel objvvm)
{
    var UserID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"].ToString();
    var objEmpDepUTID = db.UserRightsSettings
        .Where(u => u.UserID.ToString() == UserID)
        .Select(e => new
        {
            objemployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
            objdepartmentID = e.DepartmentID,
            objusertypeID = e.UserTypeID
        })
        .FirstOrDefault();

    var EmployeeID = objEmpDepUTID.objemployeeID;
    var DepartmentID = objEmpDepUTID.objdepartmentID;
    var UserTypeID = objEmpDepUTID.objusertypeID;

    if (DepartmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
       (UserTypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
       (UserTypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501"))))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index1", "NextFollowUp");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index2", "NextFollowUp");
    }
}

private ActionResult Index1()
{
    return View();
}

private ActionResult Index2()
{
    return View();
}
```

The above code is not working correctly - it doesn't hit the other action when the if condition satisfies. I tried all methods but I didn't find any solution.

Comment: Assuming your controller is called NextFollowUpController it should work.  Hit F12 and view the network activity, check the exact Url it is trying to redirect to.

Comment: Yes my controller is NextFollowup Controller which is mention in that image and i checked using Debug point. it didnt hit the Index1 Action

Comment: You need to use browser debugger, F12

Comment: ok i have a check and let you know

Comment: There is no return for VisitCount actionresult. place the return View(); and try

Comment: Please don't post images of code!

Comment: @SambathKumarS you shouldn't edit the question with what you think is the answer.

Comment: Your methods are `private`. Make them `public` (you cannot redirect to private methods)

Comment: Yes Stephen I will do and let you know

Comment: @stephen-muecke comment will work. I've also facing same issue. By making them public resolved the issue.

Comment: @StephenMuecke its working thanks:)

Comment: @DevanshNigam yes you are correct Stephen answer is correct

Comment: Yes I know :). But why have you accepted the answer you did. It is not correct and will not solve your problem (the 1st part is wrong and the 2nd part is not redirecting)

Comment: @StephenMuecke No Stephen His answer also working i checked that too but his  answer will wont work if i gave as  private instead of public. please post ur answer as comment i will mark as correct answer

Comment: @snehasusan have you added return View() in VisitCount actionresult

Comment: @SambathKumarS if i gave return View means it shows one green colour code near to return view (UnRechable code dectected) but i run the code after add return view that also working so no issue ;)

Comment: @snehasusan tag my comment if its helpful

Comment: @SambathKumarS i gave vote to you. i donno how to tag . how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot redirect to a method marked `private`. Your need to make your methods `public`.

```
public ActionResult Index1()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index2()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're inside the same controller, try this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index1");
```

Instead of:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index1", "NextFollowUp");
```

If you're calling the action from another controller, use this:

```
RedirectToAction("Index1", "NextFollowUp");
```

Or try this code:

```
return View("ActionName");
```

Like this:

```
if (DepartmentID == new Guid("47D2C992-1CB6-44AA-91CA-6AA3C338447E") &&
   (UserTypeID == new Guid("106D02CC-7DC2-42BF-AC6F-D683ADDC1824") ||
   (UserTypeID == new Guid("B3728982-0016-4562-BF73-E9B8B99BD501"))))
{
   return View("Index1");
}
else
{
    return View("Index2");
}
```